# Can removing brackets destroy diverging to +infinity of a series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I want to find an example such that after inserting parentheses in initial series, new series diverges to $+\infty$ but original series is not diverging to $+\infty$ (if such example exists).

Motivation: there are examples that show  how adding parentheses can make a series converging, for example
$$1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots $$
does not converge, but
$$(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots $$
converges. Can removing parentheses also have such an effect?

Comment: I am unable to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @copper.hat I want to find an example such that after inserting parentheses in initial series, new series diverges to +infinity but original series is not diverging to +infinity(if such example exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for some constuction like this:
Start with any two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ and let $c_1=a_1$, $c_{2n}=b_n-c_{2n-1}$, $c_{2n+1}=a_n-c_{2n}$. Then 
$$ c_1+(c_2+c_3)+(c_4+c_5)+\ldots=a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots$$
$$ (c_1+c_2)+(c_3+c_4)+(c_5+c_6)+\ldots=b_1+b_2+b_3+\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you group consecutive terms of a series with parentheses to produce a new series, the partial sums of the new series will be a subsequence of the partial sums of the old series. Therefore, if the old series converges, its sum must also be the sum of the new series.

(note that, for most arguments involving convergence, including the one above, it is more appropriate to think of sequence with limit $+\infty$ as *converging* to $+\infty$ rather than being a divergent sequence)

Comment: This is okay. But question is if new series diverging to +infinity, can we say anything about old series

Answer (score 0):

Take a symmetric random walk $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $X_k$ are i.i.d and $P(X_1 = 1) = P(X_1 = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$.

It's well known that $\limsup S_n = +\infty$ and $\liminf S_n = -\infty$.

So if we rebracket $S_n$ to approach its $\limsup$, we get an example